# American option priced incorrectly by `FinancialDerivative`?

Tags: finance

The following gives a price of 1.13:

```
FinancialDerivative[{"American", "Put"}, {"StrikePrice" -> 90, 
  "Expiration" -> 1},  {"InterestRate" -> 0.1, "Volatility" -> 0.18, 
  "CurrentPrice" -> 100, "Dividend" -> 0.}]
```

While my calculation with binomial tree gives 1.26.
This link on java agrees with my result.
http://www.math.columbia.edu/~smirnov/options13.html

What's wrong with `FinancialDerivative`?

Comment: Using the option  `Method->"Binomial"` gives `1.2625`, that is, `FinancialDerivative[{"American", "Put"}, {"StrikePrice" -> 90, 
  "Expiration" -> 1}, {"InterestRate" -> 0.1, "Volatility" -> 0.18, 
  "CurrentPrice" -> 100, "Dividend" -> 0.}, Method -> "Binomial"]`

Comment: @kglr But how is it possible to have such a large discrepancy between the two methods, binomial and Black-Scholes?

Comment: AIGuy, good point. I don't know how.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the setting `"Binomial"` for the option `Method` gives `1.2625`:

```
FinancialDerivative[{"American", "Put"}, {"StrikePrice" -> 90, 
  "Expiration" -> 1}, {"InterestRate" -> 0.1, "Volatility" -> 0.18, 
  "CurrentPrice" -> 100, "Dividend" -> 0.}, Method -> "Binomial"]
```

> 1.2625

With the default setting (`Automatic`) for this option, we get `1.13241`.